# Getting the value of a tuple using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, tuples

so I'm trying to get a tuple's value using reflection, the only problem is that I get an exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. I've tried getting its value as one comment suggested here:
[Casting to a Tuple<object,object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932387/casting-to-a-tupleobject-object), `var itemX = t.GetProperty("ItemX").GetValue(data);` If I uses lem.FieldType.GetProperty("Item1").Name , I can get the name back as Item1, Item2 , etc..., am I using it correctly or is there any other way?

```
FieldInfo[] fields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
FieldInfo[] tuples = fields.Where(field=>typeof(IStructuralEquatable).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType) && typeof(IStructuralComparable).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)).ToArray();

Debug.WriteLine(tuples.Length.ToString()" ->");
foreach (var elem in tuples)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(elem.FieldType.GetProperty("Item1").GetValue(this,null).ToString());

    PropertyInfo[] info = elem.FieldType.GetProperties();
    Debug.WriteLine(info[0].GetValue(this,null).ToString());
    for(int i=0;i<info.Length;i++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(info[i].GetValue(this,null).ToString());
    }
```

And my tuple:

```
protected Tuple<string,int, int, int> testTuple = new Tuple<string, int, int, int>("Test",1,0,1);
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] so it's more clear exactly what the problem is? Also, TargetInvocationException contains an InnerException, which is more important, can you examine it and tell us what it says?

Comment: `tuple
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => Regex.IsMatch(prop.Name, "Item[0-9]+"))
        .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(tuple));` to get all `Item1..ItemN` properties names and values

Comment: Be careful with `.ToString()` - what if `GetValue(this,null)` returns `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's *query* `tuple` for its `Item1..ItemN` properties; we can do it with a help of *Linq* and *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  Dictionary<string, object> result = testTuple
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.CanRead)
    .Where(prop => !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any())
    .Where(prop => Regex.IsMatch(prop.Name, "^Item[0-9]+$"))
    .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(testTuple));
```

Time to wrap it into your method:

```
  ...
  foreach (var tuple in tuples) {
    var result = tuple
      .GetType()
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(prop => prop.CanRead)
      .Where(prop => !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any())
      .Where(prop => Regex.IsMatch(prop.Name, "^Item[0-9]+$"))
      .Select(prop => new {
         name  = prop.Name,
         value = prop.GetValue(tuple), 
       });

    foreach (var item in result)
      Debug.WriteLine($"{item.name} = {item.value}");
  }
  ...
```

**Edit:** let's start from getting all *fields* which are of type `Tuple<,...,>` (see comments below):

```
  Object objectToInspect = this;

  HashSet<Type> typleTypes = new HashSet<Type>() {
    typeof(Tuple<>),
    typeof(Tuple<,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,,>),
  };

  var fieldsWithTuples = objectToInspect
    .GetType()
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
               BindingFlags.Instance |
               BindingFlags.Public |
               BindingFlags.Static |
               BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
    .Where(field => field.FieldType.IsGenericType)
    .Where(field => typleTypes.Contains(field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
    .Select(field => new {
      name  = field.Name,
      value = field.GetValue(field.IsStatic
                 ? null                     // we should provide null for static
                 : objectToInspect)
    })
    .Where(item => item.value != null);
 // .Select(item => item.value) // if you want tuple values
 // .ToArray();                 // materialized as an array
```

And now we are ready to use my code above:

```
  foreach (var tuple in fieldsWithTuples.Select(f => f.value)) {
    var result = tuple
      .GetType()
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(prop => prop.CanRead)
      .Where(prop => !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any())
      .Where(prop => Regex.IsMatch(prop.Name, "^Item[0-9]+$"))
      .Select(prop => new {
         name  = prop.Name,
         value = prop.GetValue(tuple), 
       });

    foreach (var item in result)
      Debug.WriteLine($"{item.name} = {item.value}");
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help me. I had to change tupe.GetType() to tuple.FieldType, but it still throws an exception : Error verifying System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex, I added how my tuple looks like

Comment: @porsekin: something wrong with `FieldInfo[] tuples = fields...` fragment. As far as I can see, you have an object which has *fields* of type `Tuple<...>` which you want to print out. Is it your case?

Comment: yes, I can get those fields into the tuples array. I want to print out every value of each tuple in the class. Added code how I get the `fields`.

Comment: If I remove `.Where(prop => Regex.IsMatch(prop.Name, "^Item[0-9]+$"))`, I get a `System.MethodAccessException` for `value = prop.GetValue(tuple)`

Comment: @porsekin: obtaining all frields of type `Tuple<>` (as well as `Tuple<,>`, `Tuple<,,>` etc) is not trivial; see my edit

Comment: Thank you for taking your time with this amazing example, unfortunately the `System.MethodAccessException: Error verifying System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` still present. If I remove everything from foreach and only print out the `var tuple` itself, I get back every value as ('Test',1,0,1), so I don't really know what could be the problem. Or maybe bacuse I'm calling it from a subclass?

Comment: @porsekin: do you have the exception if you put, say `.Where(prop => prop.Name.StartsWith("Item"))`?

Comment: Yes, but now only `System.MethodAccessException: Error verifying <Namespace>.<Class>`

Comment: If I remove `value = prop.GetValue(tuple)` part it works, but without the values

Comment: Thank you! Managed to modify your code to make it work with:
`foreach (var tuple in fieldsWithTuples.Select(f => f.value))
                {
                    foreach (var prop in tuple.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                       var value = tuple.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(tuple,null);
                        if(value != null)
                        {
                            // do stuff
                        }
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is defined like this: `Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest>`.

Following the number of values inside tuple its not the same logic 
so to read tuple in all case (even with 8 items or more) with reflection just use this piece of code (general coding):

```
    public IEnumerable<object> EnumerateValueTuple(object valueTuple)
    {
        var tuples = new Queue<object>();
        tuples.Enqueue(valueTuple);

        while (tuples.Count > 0 && tuples.Dequeue() is object tuple)
        {
            foreach (var field in tuple.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                if (field.Name == "Rest")
                    tuples.Enqueue(field.GetValue(tuple));
                else
                    yield return field.GetValue(tuple);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could use:

```
var item = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);

foreach(var value in EnumerateValueTuple(item))
  Console.Out.WriteLine(value); // Prints "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. but it is for ValueTuple extension which is not what I want to use. If I try to use it for tuples, I get System.MethodAccessException.